# Error installing Glassfish Server Tools in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

Since yesterday afternoon I had trouble installing Glassfish Server Tools in Eclipse Indigo and Juno, I tried it on several computers and even in different places, in spite of this, error is always the same.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish,4.2.1.201201241947.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 5366f96e7efd38d97445848eafaa0ed4 and found ed73a6517d24fd8099c3a4768e61744c.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.glassfish,2.0.1.201201241947.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 1dbc10b2ac7027cae9c370de3adc984c and found f2db568f92aeb241eca747deceb23814.
```

What could cause this error? How to fix? Oracle has a bug?

Can anyone confirm if the same happens?

Comment: I confirm the error in Indigo upon dl of the oracle connector for the glassfish servers. I'm not seeing it in Juno 64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> have you tried downloading and installing glass fish manually ? and then adding the your installation to the server's window in eclipse ? or what other things have you tried ?

**UPDATE:**

Just to prevent people from downvoting me, please **refer to the answer given by "dangling_pointer"**, his answer is given in a more constructive way and it provides links and steps in how to do it. So even if both answers end up telling you the same thing, one shows the steps to get there.

Comment: Because your answer provides no insight or course of action. The answer provided by dangling_pointer provides some guidance rather than simply questioning the competence of the asker. Explaining how to do a manual installation would have been a good answer, not simply asking if it had already been tried.

Comment: You are right in a certain way, but, i was giving my answer in the form of a question, cause i had the same problem and that was what i did, and just in case he had already tried that, i could have updated the answer. But, if you see dangling_pointer answer, you will realize that he is telling him how to installed manually.

Comment: Yes, he suggests that and then provides the a link and guide to do so. Without knowing how to install it manually the suggestion is useless, which is why I voted yours down and his up despite the fact that at their core both answers are the same.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I tried to install GlassFish server adapter through "New server wizard" in my Eclipse Juno IDE.

Eventually I succeeded to install *Oracle GlassFish Server Tools* by going to Help -> Install New Software... and entering this site location: http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno (if you use other Eclipse edition end it with appropriate suffix).

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. It turns out that turning off the anti-virus solved it.
Don't ask me why...
Eclipse Juno and AVG antivirus